# Issue with offset function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using :

```
var pos = $("#" + index).offset().top;
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos});
```

`index` is an incrementing variable which is passed from some other method.
But it is returning me wrong offset position for first 50 indexes after that it is working fine.

Is there something, I am doing wrong?

Comment: without seeing an enviroment where it works in this cannot be answered. Can you add a stack snippet where we can see the problem in action?

Comment: Try adding setTimeout, because sometime till page loads, some values do not calculate in that time, but after, and they do not get the right value.

Comment: Maybe the ids are not correct. Share your HTML and a working example. It should work

Answer (score 0):

var pos = document.getElementById('index');
pos.getBoundingClientRect();

This worked for me fine.
But thanks all for your help.